# How to position elements to the right in md-toolbar?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using FAB speed dial within a toolbar. However I am unable to have it floating to the right of the toolbar. I've tried `float: right` with no luck. Also, tried flex `offset="55"`, but this doesn't work when the window is resized. Essentially, regardless of the window size, I would like the button sitting on the far right within the blue toolbar container.

See photo and code below:

[image: toolbar]

```
<md-toolbar layout-fill layout-padding layout="row" style="background-color: #3F51B5;color:white;text-align:text-center;">
    <div layout="row">
        <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x" flex></i>
        <h1 class="md-title" style="color:white">Org Chart</h1>                                 
    </div>  
    <div class="lock-size" flex offset="55">
        <md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="left" ng-class="md-fling">
            <md-fab-trigger>
                <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-accent">
                    <md-tooltip>
                      Actions
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_view_module_48px.svg"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-trigger>
            <md-fab-actions>
                <md-button aria-label="view" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" >
                    <md-tooltip>
                      View Chart
                    </md-tooltip>                               
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.read" ng-click="paneShowFn('read')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="add" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" >
                    <md-tooltip>
                      Add Chart
                    </md-tooltip>                               
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_add_48px.svg" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.insert" ng-click="paneShowFn('insert')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="Settings" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" >
                    <md-tooltip>
                      Security Access
                    </md-tooltip>                               
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_add_48px.svg" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.permission" ng-click="paneShowFn('permission')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>                                
                <md-button aria-label="edit" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.update" ng-click="paneShowFn('update')">
                    <md-tooltip>
                      Edit Chart
                    </md-tooltip>                               
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_edit_48px.svg" style="color:black"></md-icon>
                </md-button>                                
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-fab-speed-dial>
    </div>  
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: What about adding in the md-position-mode="target-right target" to you rmenu?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**THIS SOLUTION IS FOR ANGULAR MATERIAL v1.X, IF YOU NEED AN UNIVERSAL/ANGULAR MATERIAL v2 SOLUTION CHECK @experimenter ANSWER**

If you have a `md-toolbar` the easiest way to align right content is like this:

```
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h3>You text</h3>
            <span flex></span>
            <ANY>your right content</ANY>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
```

The `flex` property in `span` will cover the space between the contents. This is the official way in documentation.

In you example, you just need:

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <div layout="row">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x" flex></i>
            <h1 class="md-title" style="color:white">Org Chart</h1>
        </div>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="left" ng-class="md-fling">
            <md-fab-trigger>
                <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-accent">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Actions
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_view_module_48px.svg"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-trigger>
            <md-fab-actions>
                <md-button aria-label="view" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        View Chart
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.read" ng-click="paneShowFn('read')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="add" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Add Chart
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_add_48px.svg" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.insert" ng-click="paneShowFn('insert')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="Settings" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Security Access
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_add_48px.svg" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.permission" ng-click="paneShowFn('permission')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="edit" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.update" ng-click="paneShowFn('update')">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Edit Chart
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_edit_48px.svg" style="color:black"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-fab-speed-dial>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Np :) you can edit your title for somehting more generic like "how to posit elements in md-toolbar's right". But with proper english xD

Comment: I tried the solution suggested by you and it just brings the component down to next row.

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary Are you using angular material v1? I think that this solution doesn't work with angular 2 version

Comment: I am using ng2 and the below answer addresses it.

Answer (score 72):

Or you can use a class for that:

```css
.fill-space {
  // This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox.
  // Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout.
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Application Title</span>

  <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
  <span class="fill-space"></span>

  <span>Right Aligned Text</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

This solution is also taken from a spec.

Comment: Why would you need to do that when `<span flex></span>` works perctly well and is the recommended practice?

Comment: @camden_kid <span flex></span> doesn't work in my case. Probably because I use newer version of Angular Material v2 not Angular Material v1.x!

Comment: @camden_kid I think it can stay. I was looking this question for Material 2 and the google lead me here. The solution is universal and shows how it works in general, so it's good for deeper understanding the question in all cases.

Comment: `This solution is also taken from a spec.`: Could you provide a link for reference?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov I guess [this](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview) is the link you are looking for. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Anyone who finds this solution to not work, it may be because `//` is not a comment in CSS.